# CSS thumbnail with icon overlay

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: Need something like this]

So basically I need to set icons / labels over the thumbnail picture, how to do it with CSS and HTML? If possible I need it to be responsive. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry for not posting code, here is what I have tried using Bootstrap 3 and Font Awesome:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
        <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="img/test/test04.png" alt="thumb01">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="delivery alert alert-success">
                    <i class="fa fa-truck" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Delivery class:

```
.delivery{
position: absolute;
font-size: large;}
```

Comment: please share what you have tried\

Comment: Did you try to create element with background-image and add the logo with absolute position to the bottom?

Comment: What you want that we write code just by seeing your image :/ we are not an image processing AI

Comment: The best approach will be CSS sprites technique.

Comment: please provide some code you've tried, this is not a coding service

Comment: get some idea for using Use bootstrap-4 for https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/ `card` & `flex` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Firstly, if you are using some framework, look for a solution that uses it. Secondly, if you do not use a structure, you can use `@media` in CSS to make your elements responsives, and for the layout, what you are looking for is a **thumbnail** or **picture card**, search for it in internet if you encounter difficulties. You can work using the image and the icons inside a `div`, then just work with the elements using CSS (`display` and the `float`, for example). Have fun :)